# $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$ in distributional sense implies $f$ is holomorphic

Tags: cv.complex-variables, schwartz-distributions, several-complex-variables

Let $f=(u,v)\in \mathscr{D}'(U,\mathbb{C})$ be a distribution, where $U\subset\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set and $u$ and $v$ are the projection of $f$ onto the real and imaginary axis (ie $\langle f,\phi\rangle=\langle u,\phi\rangle+i\langle v,\phi\rangle$). Suppose that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}f=0\qquad\text{in U,}
$$
where $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)$ and the derivatives are in distributional sense.
Does it follow that $f$ is holomorphic in the classical sense, ie $f\in C^\infty(U,\mathbb{C})$ and the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied?

The obvious idea would be to mollify, get holomorphic functions and then take the limit. But how can we conclude that the limit is still holomorphic?

Comment: That is called the Weyl lemma.

Comment: @BenMcKay Doesn't the Weyl Lemma require $f\in L^1_{loc}$?

Comment: no: see Folland's Real Analysis, p. 308.

Comment: Thanks. I knew the proof on Folland for tempered distributions but I never noticed that the same proof also holds for distributions in $\mathscr{D}'$. Very nice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just realized that, if $f$ is in $L^1_{loc}$ and not just in $\mathscr{D}'$, my question can be answered using Weyl's lemma for harmonic functions. Indeed, from $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$ it easily follows that $\Delta u=\Delta v=0$, and then Weyl's lemma implies that $u$ and $v$ are smooth. But then $f$ is smooth and satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, thus is holomorphic.

EDIT: As pointed out by Ben McKay in the comments, the hypothesis that $f\in L^1_{loc}$ is not necessary.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to replace the Cauchy integral formula $f_n(z)=\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{|s-a|=r} \frac{f_n(s)}{s-z}ds$ on a circle

by one on an annulus
$$f_n(z)=\int_r^R \psi_{r,R}(t)\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{|s-a|=t} \frac{f_n(s)}{s-z}ds dt\label{1}\tag{1}$$

where $f_n= f\ast \phi_n$ is a mollified version of $f$, so $f_n$ is smooth and holomorphic on a slightly smaller open $U_n$, and
$\psi_{r,R}\in C^\infty_c(r,R),\int \psi_{r,R}=1$.

Equation \eqref{1} is an integral of $f_n$ against a $C^\infty_c(\Bbb{C})$ function $h_z$ where (locally) $z\to h_z$  is continuous in the $C^\infty_c$ topology,
so there won't be any problem when letting $n\to \infty$, obtaining the local uniform convergence of $f_n$ to an analytic function representing $f$.

Comment: To obtain the local uniform convergence at last line you're using that $f_n\to f$ with respect to the strong topology of $\mathscr{D}'$, right?

Comment: (for $|z-a|<r$ with $r$ small enough so that the disk is contained in some $U_n$) $z\to \langle f,h_z\rangle$ is a continuous and clearly holomorphic function and $f_n(z)= \langle f, \phi_n\ast h_z\rangle$ converges to it pointwise and in the sense of disttributions. @Titti

Comment: I agree, but we want to show $f=[z\mapsto \langle f,h_z\rangle]$ as a distribution. For a test function $\varphi$, we know $\langle\langle f_n(w),h(z,w)\rangle,\varphi(z)\rangle=\langle f_n(z),\varphi(z)\rangle\to\langle f(z),\varphi(z)\rangle$. But to conclude we must also show $\langle\langle f_n(w),h(z,w)\rangle,\varphi(z)\rangle\to\langle\langle f(w),h(z,w)\rangle,\varphi(z)\rangle$, and this is true because $\langle f_n(w),h(z,w)\rangle\to \langle f(w),h(z,w)\rangle$ uniformly in $z$ (since $f_n\to f$ wrt the strong topology of $\mathscr{D}'$).